# Add labels to factor based on data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with numeric data like this:

```
data <- data.frame(q1=c("2", "1", "3"),
                   q2=c("1", "3", "2"),
                   other=c("other", "other", "other"))
```

I would like to treat that data as factors and add factor labels to that data. I would still like to see the numeric data so that I can perform mathematic functions, but see the labels in ggplot, etc. The factor labels are in another data frame, like this:

```
factors <- data.frame(variable=c("q1", "q1", "q1", "q2", "q2", "q2"),
                      level=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                      labels=c("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y", "Z"))
```

How can I use the `factors` df to add labels to the `data` df?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
labelled <- data %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("q")),
            .funs = funs((., 
                                labels=factors$labels
                                )))
```

I am sure there is some simple way I am not considering.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you want your data to be numeric, don't put quotes around the numbers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to loop over the 'q' columns with `imap`, subset the 'level' and 'labels' column from the 'factors' dataset  based on the column name, and specify that in the `factor`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data1 <- imap_dfr(data[startsWith(names(data), 'q')], ~ 
           {i1 <- factors$variable == .y
          factor(.x, levels = factors$level[i1], 
              labels = factors$labels[i1]) }) %>%
   bind_cols(., data %>% select(other))

str(data1)
#tibble [3 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ q1   : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 2 1 3
# $ q2   : Factor w/ 3 levels "X","Y","Z": 1 3 2
# $ other: Factor w/ 1 level "other": 1 1 1
```

Comment: I tried that, but got an error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @AnthonySchmidt I am not able to reproduce the error.  Can you show the package versions of dplyr and purrr

Comment: I'll try it again and come back to respond.

Comment: @AnthonySchmidt I am a bit surprised because these. are standard functions.  Not sure it would have a different behavior in different versions

Comment: It certainly worked with the example data above, but when modifying it to refer to my real data, I got that error. I have found a workaround, though. I will continue to play with this, though, because it is far more parsimonious.

Comment: @AnthonySchmidt if you can update your post with the `dput` of a small example that shows this behavior, it would be easier to debug.  Also, can you check the `str(yourdata)` for the class of the variable and if there are any leading/lagging spaces